# Pass a variable from AppDelegate to other ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have this block of code in my AppDelegate

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        
        fcmTokenString = fcmToken
        
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

as you can see I have access to `fcmToken` variable while I am in AppDelegate.
I can confirm it is working, because I see the token printing out in the console.

[image]

## Now

I want to access this variable later on the code on my LoginVC.

```
print(fcmToken)
```

> c1DdtdDF1Rs:APA91bGJBUD65nidQiFDO90AVNgq0wiMjUaZmZXVJ8c_tYmFe5dkmgweOdO10jzPRlMVZF_qNyWMMsu7EhA5IMVo3jLWvBThDteR7WWUPqau-ZFAHKQPHgI5Vb48vA-_4nwkZCKrOVoT

***Note:** Only after the user login success which is inside LoginVC that is when I need to create a record in my Firebase database. In order to create that record, I need fcmToken from AppDelegate.*

What is the cleanest way to do that?

Comment: Why can't you add an observer for that notification in the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a var inside the AppDelegate

```
var fcmToken:String?
```

assign it inside the callback , then access it with in any vc

```
let de = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
if let token = de.fcmToken {

}
```

The problem with your current solution is that posting the notification may occur before the vc is shown ( means before it registers as an observer so it will loss the token )

---

You can observe the changes with

```
   var tokenTimer:Timer!  // why timer ? as sometimes token changed and firInstanceIDTokenRefresh not fired also you can get rid of firInstanceIDTokenRefresh  implementation 

    // put these inside AppDelegate didFinishLaunching...
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    self.tokenTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.3,
                                            target: self,
                                            selector: #selector(self.checkToken),
                                            userInfo: nil,
                                            repeats: true)

@objc func checkToken()
{
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
         
          print("retrieved \(refreshedToken)") 
          
          fcmToken = refreshedToken
    }
    else{
        
        print("not retrieved yet")
        
        
    }
}
@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
    
          print("retrieved \(refreshedToken)") 
           
            fcmToken = refreshedToken
     }
}
```

Sometimes firebase glitches and delay sending the token , so it's a recommended way to send the token to your server every launch of app to keep track of refresh and possibility of nil uploaded token before

Comment: what should we put in the if let block for success case ?

Comment: Also what if it is failing ? Should we add the elese ?

Comment: it's a matter of fail i know , but let me give you the workaround

Answer (score 1):

You have to get reference to `AppDelegate` of `shared` instance of `UIApplication`.

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

then you can access your variable from delegate

```
delegate.fcmToken
```

Answer (score 1):

first define a variable in your AppDelegate class:

```
class AppDelegate {
    var myToken: String?
    // code in your app delegate
}
```

add this line to your function:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    fcmTokenString = fcmToken
    self.myToken = fcmToken

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

}
```

then you can access 'myToken' variable throw your AppDelegate reference(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! Appdelegate)

in your vc:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

then you can use this:

```
appDelegate.myToken
```

Comment: update your answer include how to access it from other VC.

Answer (score 0):

Without Force Unwrapping,

```
func appDelegate() -> AppDelegate? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    return appDelegate
}
```

access `fcmToken` variable from the `appDelegate()` instance

```
appDelegate().fcmToken
```